# How to enable localStorage in QWebView?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, webview, qt5

I have a webview in a Qt application. I create it using:

```
QWebView *view = new QWebView();
```

and then I do:

```
view->load(QUrl(...));
```

and

```
view->show();
```

---

Instead of an empty object, `localStorage` is `null`. I guess I need to enable it somewhere on the Qt side.

How can I enable `localStorage` in a `QWebView`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
QWebSettings *settings = view->settings();
settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalStorageEnabled, true);
```

Then you can specify the path:

```
settings->setLocalStoragePath("desired/path")
```

List of available Attributes and other methods related to `QWebSettings` is here - [QtDoc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebsettings.html#WebAttribute-enum)

Comment: @IonicăBizău added at the end of answer